# using virtualenvwrapper to install custom python version

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

My `ubuntu lucid` has `python2.6.` I installed `python3.3.1` by compiling the source.I want to organize this using virtualenvwrapper.

I have installed virtualenvwrapper and set `WORKON_HOME` to `/home/me/.virtualenvs`.I need to create an env called envpy331 which has python 3.3.1 .When I try to run

`mkvirtualenv envpy331`

It creates an env with python2.6 .How do I specify the required python version(ie python 3.3.1) ?

Comment: Specify the Python executable with `--python=/path/to/python`.

Comment: thanks.. should have read the docs .. if you can convert this into an answer ,I could accept + close this